# i want to find the max of the count (*)

Tags: sqlite

```
select distinct WAR.Name as 'Ονομασία Πολέμου',
            WAR.War_ID as 'Κωδικός Πολέμου',
            count(*) as 'Αριθμός Πλοίων',
            max(SHIP.ship_name)
from WAR,AT_WAR,SHIP
where SHIP.Ship_Name=AT_WAR.Ship_Name 
and WAR.War_ID=AT_WAR.War_ID
group by SHIP.Ship_Name``
having count(SHIP.Ship_Name)
```

Comment: if you are receiving some error, please share with us and edit question with proper details about your issue.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: it wasn;t a screen shot .i wrote that.can i give a screen shot of the table of data base?